# tinyusb: can't set config on USB device

Tags: c++, c, embedded, usb, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm using tinyusb in RPI Pico SDK to allow my device to communicate with host computer through USB 1.1 port. I'm not sure if the fact that my project is RPI Pico based is important or not, as I feel that my problems come from misunderstanding how to use tinyusb library rather than some hardware dependencies.

Anyway, I have the following code for tusb_config.h file:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------+
// Board Specific Configuration
//--------------------------------------------------------------------+

// RHPort number used for device can be defined by board.mk, default to port 0
#ifndef BOARD_TUD_RHPORT
#define BOARD_TUD_RHPORT      0
#endif

// RHPort max operational speed can defined by board.mk
#ifndef BOARD_TUD_MAX_SPEED
#define BOARD_TUD_MAX_SPEED   OPT_MODE_DEFAULT_SPEED
#endif

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// COMMON CONFIGURATION
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

// defined by compiler flags for flexibility
#ifndef CFG_TUSB_MCU
#define CFG_TUSB_MCU OPT_MCU_RP2040
#endif

#ifndef CFG_TUSB_OS
#define CFG_TUSB_OS               OPT_OS_NONE
#endif

#ifndef CFG_TUSB_DEBUG
#define CFG_TUSB_DEBUG            0
#endif

// Enable Device stack
#define CFG_TUD_ENABLED           1

// Default is max speed that hardware controller could support with on-chip PHY
#define CFG_TUD_MAX_SPEED         BOARD_TUD_MAX_SPEED

/* USB DMA on some MCUs can only access a specific SRAM region with restriction on alignment.
* Tinyusb use follows macros to declare transferring memory so that they can be put
* into those specific section.
* e.g
* - CFG_TUSB_MEM SECTION : __attribute__ (( section(".usb_ram") ))
* - CFG_TUSB_MEM_ALIGN   : __attribute__ ((aligned(4)))
*/
#ifndef CFG_TUSB_MEM_SECTION
#define CFG_TUSB_MEM_SECTION
#endif

#ifndef CFG_TUSB_MEM_ALIGN
#define CFG_TUSB_MEM_ALIGN        __attribute__ ((aligned(4)))
#endif

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEVICE CONFIGURATION
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef CFG_TUD_ENDPOINT0_SIZE
#define CFG_TUD_ENDPOINT0_SIZE    64
#endif

//------------- CLASS -------------//
#define CFG_TUD_AUDIO             1
#define CFG_TUD_CDC               0
#define CFG_TUD_MSC               0
#define CFG_TUD_HID               0
#define CFG_TUD_MIDI              0
#define CFG_TUD_VENDOR            0

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// AUDIO CLASS DRIVER CONFIGURATION
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

// Have a look into audio_device.h for all configurations

#define CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_DESC_LEN                 TUD_AUDIO_MIC_FOUR_CH_DESC_LEN

#define CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_N_AS_INT                 1
#define CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_CTRL_BUF_SZ              64

#define CFG_TUD_AUDIO_ENABLE_EP_IN                    1
#define CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_N_BYTES_PER_SAMPLE_TX    2         // This value is not required by the driver, it parses this information from the descriptor once the alternate interface is set by the host - we use it for the setup
#define CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_N_CHANNELS_TX            1         // This value is not required by the driver, it parses this information from the descriptor once the alternate interface is set by the host - we use it for the setup
#define CFG_TUD_AUDIO_EP_SZ_IN                        48 * CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_N_BYTES_PER_SAMPLE_TX * CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_N_CHANNELS_TX
#define CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_EP_IN_SZ_MAX             CFG_TUD_AUDIO_EP_SZ_IN
#define CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_EP_IN_SW_BUF_SZ          CFG_TUD_AUDIO_EP_SZ_IN

#define CFG_TUD_AUDIO_ENABLE_ENCODING                 1
#define CFG_TUD_AUDIO_ENABLE_TYPE_I_ENCODING          1
#define CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_CHANNEL_PER_FIFO_TX      1
#define CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_N_TX_SUPP_SW_FIFO        (CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_N_CHANNELS_TX / CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_CHANNEL_PER_FIFO_TX)
#define CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_TX_SUPP_SW_FIFO_SZ       (CFG_TUD_AUDIO_EP_SZ_IN / CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_N_TX_SUPP_SW_FIFO)
```

And here is the code for descriptors and callbacks:

```
#include "tusb.h"
#include "class/audio/audio.h"
#include "device/usbd.h"

/* A combination of interfaces must have a unique product id, since PC will save device driver after the first plug.
* Same VID/PID with different interface e.g MSC (first), then CDC (later) will possibly cause system error on PC.
*
* Auto ProductID layout's Bitmap:
*   [MSB]     AUDIO | MIDI | HID | MSC | CDC          [LSB]
*/
#define _PID_MAP(itf, n)  ( (CFG_TUD_##itf) << (n) )
#define USB_PID           (0x4000 | _PID_MAP(CDC, 0) | _PID_MAP(MSC, 1) | _PID_MAP(HID, 2) | \
    _PID_MAP(MIDI, 3) | _PID_MAP(AUDIO, 4) | _PID_MAP(VENDOR, 5) )

//--------------------------------------------------------------------+
// Device Descriptors
//--------------------------------------------------------------------+
tusb_desc_device_t const desc_device =
{
    .bLength            = sizeof(tusb_desc_device_t),
    .bDescriptorType    = TUSB_DESC_DEVICE,
    .bcdUSB             = 0x0200,

    // Use Interface Association Descriptor (IAD) for Audio
    // As required by USB Specs IAD's subclass must be common class (2) and protocol must be IAD (1)
    .bDeviceClass       = TUSB_CLASS_MISC,
    .bDeviceSubClass    = MISC_SUBCLASS_COMMON,
    .bDeviceProtocol    = MISC_PROTOCOL_IAD,
    .bMaxPacketSize0    = CFG_TUD_ENDPOINT0_SIZE,

    .idVendor           = 0xFED0,
    .idProduct          = USB_PID,
    .bcdDevice          = 0x0100,

    .iManufacturer      = 0x01,
    .iProduct           = 0x02,
    .iSerialNumber      = 0x03,

    .bNumConfigurations = 0x01
};

// Invoked when received GET DEVICE DESCRIPTOR
// Application return pointer to descriptor
uint8_t const * tud_descriptor_device_cb(void)
{
  return (uint8_t const *) &desc_device;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------+
// Configuration Descriptor
//--------------------------------------------------------------------+
enum
{
  ITF_NUM_AUDIO_CONTROL = 0,
  ITF_NUM_AUDIO_STREAMING,
  ITF_NUM_TOTAL
};

#define CONFIG_TOTAL_LEN        (TUD_CONFIG_DESC_LEN + CFG_TUD_AUDIO * TUD_AUDIO_MIC_ONE_CH_DESC_LEN)

#define EPNUM_AUDIO   0x01

uint8_t const desc_configuration[] =
{
  // Config number, interface count, string index, total length, attribute, power in mA
  TUD_CONFIG_DESCRIPTOR(1, ITF_NUM_TOTAL, 0, CONFIG_TOTAL_LEN, 0x00, 500),

  // Interface number, string index, EP Out & EP In address, EP size
  TUD_AUDIO_MIC_ONE_CH_DESCRIPTOR(/*_itfnum*/ ITF_NUM_AUDIO_CONTROL, /*_stridx*/ 0, /*_nBytesPerSample*/ CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_N_BYTES_PER_SAMPLE_TX, /*_nBitsUsedPerSample*/ CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_N_BYTES_PER_SAMPLE_TX*8, /*_epin*/ 0x80 | EPNUM_AUDIO, /*_epsize*/ CFG_TUD_AUDIO_EP_SZ_IN)
};

// Invoked when received GET CONFIGURATION DESCRIPTOR
// Application return pointer to descriptor
// Descriptor contents must exist long enough for transfer to complete
uint8_t const * tud_descriptor_configuration_cb(uint8_t index)
{
  (void) index; // for multiple configurations
  return desc_configuration;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------+
// String Descriptors
//--------------------------------------------------------------------+

// array of pointer to string descriptors
char const* string_desc_arr [] =
{
    (const char[]) { 0x09, 0x04 },  // 0: is supported language is English (0x0409)
    "PookyFan",                     // 1: Manufacturer
    "PicoMic",                      // 2: Product
    "42069",                        // 3: Serials, should use chip ID
    "UAC2",                         // 4: Audio Interface
};

static uint16_t _desc_str[32];

// Invoked when received GET STRING DESCRIPTOR request
// Application return pointer to descriptor, whose contents must exist long enough for transfer to complete
uint16_t const* tud_descriptor_string_cb(uint8_t index, uint16_t langid)
{
  (void) langid;

  uint8_t chr_count;

  if ( index == 0)
  {
    memcpy(&_desc_str[1], string_desc_arr[0], 2);
    chr_count = 1;
  }else
  {
    // Convert ASCII string into UTF-16

    if ( !(index < sizeof(string_desc_arr)/sizeof(string_desc_arr[0])) ) return NULL;

    const char* str = string_desc_arr[index];

    // Cap at max char
    chr_count = (uint8_t) strlen(str);
    if ( chr_count > 31 ) chr_count = 31;

    for(uint8_t i=0; i<chr_count; i++)
    {
      _desc_str[1+i] = str[i];
    }
  }

  // first byte is length (including header), second byte is string type
  _desc_str[0] = (uint16_t) ((TUSB_DESC_STRING << 8 ) | (2*chr_count + 2));

  return _desc_str;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////

// Audio controls
// Current states
bool mute[CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_N_CHANNELS_TX + 1];                        // +1 for master channel 0
uint16_t volume[CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_N_CHANNELS_TX + 1];                    // +1 for master channel 0
uint32_t sampFreq;
uint8_t clkValid;

// Range states
audio_control_range_2_n_t(1) volumeRng[CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_N_CHANNELS_TX+1];           // Volume range state
audio_control_range_4_n_t(1) sampleFreqRng;                         // Sample frequency range state

constexpr auto AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE = 48000;
void initUsbRanges()
{
  sampleFreqRng.wNumSubRanges = 1;
  sampleFreqRng.subrange[0].bMin = AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE;
  sampleFreqRng.subrange[0].bMax = AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE;
  sampleFreqRng.subrange[0].bRes = 0;
}

/* Device callbacks */
// Invoked when device is mounted
void tud_mount_cb()
{
  //todo: needed?
}

// Invoked when device is unmounted
void tud_umount_cb()
{
  //todo: needed?
}

// Invoked when usb bus is suspended
// remote_wakeup_en : if host allow us  to perform remote wakeup
// Within 7ms, device must draw an average of current less than 2.5 mA from bus
void tud_suspend_cb(bool remote_wakeup_en)
{
  //todo: needed?
}

// Invoked when usb bus is resumed
void tud_resume_cb(void)
{
  //todo: needed?
}

// Invoked when audio class specific set request received for an EP
bool tud_audio_set_req_ep_cb(uint8_t rhport, tusb_control_request_t const * p_request, uint8_t *pBuff)
{
  (void) rhport;
  (void) pBuff;

  // We do not support any set range requests here, only current value requests
  TU_VERIFY(p_request->bRequest == AUDIO_CS_REQ_CUR);

  // Page 91 in UAC2 specification
  uint8_t channelNum = TU_U16_LOW(p_request->wValue);
  uint8_t ctrlSel = TU_U16_HIGH(p_request->wValue);
  uint8_t ep = TU_U16_LOW(p_request->wIndex);

  (void) channelNum; (void) ctrlSel; (void) ep;

  return false;     // Yet not implemented
}

// Invoked when audio class specific set request received for an interface
bool tud_audio_set_req_itf_cb(uint8_t rhport, tusb_control_request_t const * p_request, uint8_t *pBuff)
{
  (void) rhport;
  (void) pBuff;

  // We do not support any set range requests here, only current value requests
  TU_VERIFY(p_request->bRequest == AUDIO_CS_REQ_CUR);

  // Page 91 in UAC2 specification
  uint8_t channelNum = TU_U16_LOW(p_request->wValue);
  uint8_t ctrlSel = TU_U16_HIGH(p_request->wValue);
  uint8_t itf = TU_U16_LOW(p_request->wIndex);

  (void) channelNum; (void) ctrlSel; (void) itf;

  return false;     // Yet not implemented
}

// Invoked when audio class specific set request received for an entity
bool tud_audio_set_req_entity_cb(uint8_t rhport, tusb_control_request_t const * p_request, uint8_t *pBuff)
{
  (void) rhport;

  // Page 91 in UAC2 specification
  uint8_t channelNum = TU_U16_LOW(p_request->wValue);
  uint8_t ctrlSel = TU_U16_HIGH(p_request->wValue);
  uint8_t itf = TU_U16_LOW(p_request->wIndex);
  uint8_t entityID = TU_U16_HIGH(p_request->wIndex);

  (void) itf;

  // We do not support any set range requests here, only current value requests
  TU_VERIFY(p_request->bRequest == AUDIO_CS_REQ_CUR);

  // If request is for our feature unit
  if ( entityID == 2 )
  {
    switch ( ctrlSel )
    {
      case AUDIO_FU_CTRL_MUTE:
        // Request uses format layout 1
        TU_VERIFY(p_request->wLength == sizeof(audio_control_cur_1_t));

        mute[channelNum] = ((audio_control_cur_1_t*) pBuff)->bCur;

        TU_LOG2("    Set Mute: %d of channel: %u\r\n", mute[channelNum], channelNum);
      return true;

      case AUDIO_FU_CTRL_VOLUME:
        // Request uses format layout 2
        TU_VERIFY(p_request->wLength == sizeof(audio_control_cur_2_t));

        volume[channelNum] = (uint16_t) ((audio_control_cur_2_t*) pBuff)->bCur;

        TU_LOG2("    Set Volume: %d dB of channel: %u\r\n", volume[channelNum], channelNum);
      return true;

        // Unknown/Unsupported control
      default:
        TU_BREAKPOINT();
      return false;
    }
  }
  return false;    // Yet not implemented
}

// Invoked when audio class specific get request received for an EP
bool tud_audio_get_req_ep_cb(uint8_t rhport, tusb_control_request_t const * p_request)
{
  (void) rhport;

  // Page 91 in UAC2 specification
  uint8_t channelNum = TU_U16_LOW(p_request->wValue);
  uint8_t ctrlSel = TU_U16_HIGH(p_request->wValue);
  uint8_t ep = TU_U16_LOW(p_request->wIndex);

  (void) channelNum; (void) ctrlSel; (void) ep;

  //    return tud_control_xfer(rhport, p_request, &tmp, 1);

  return false;     // Yet not implemented
}

// Invoked when audio class specific get request received for an interface
bool tud_audio_get_req_itf_cb(uint8_t rhport, tusb_control_request_t const * p_request)
{
  (void) rhport;

  // Page 91 in UAC2 specification
  uint8_t channelNum = TU_U16_LOW(p_request->wValue);
  uint8_t ctrlSel = TU_U16_HIGH(p_request->wValue);
  uint8_t itf = TU_U16_LOW(p_request->wIndex);

  (void) channelNum; (void) ctrlSel; (void) itf;

  return false;     // Yet not implemented
}

// Invoked when audio class specific get request received for an entity
bool tud_audio_get_req_entity_cb(uint8_t rhport, tusb_control_request_t const * p_request)
{
  (void) rhport;

  // Page 91 in UAC2 specification
  uint8_t channelNum = TU_U16_LOW(p_request->wValue);
  uint8_t ctrlSel = TU_U16_HIGH(p_request->wValue);
  // uint8_t itf = TU_U16_LOW(p_request->wIndex);           // Since we have only one audio function implemented, we do not need the itf value
  uint8_t entityID = TU_U16_HIGH(p_request->wIndex);

  // Input terminal (Microphone input)
  if (entityID == 1)
  {
    switch ( ctrlSel )
    {
      case AUDIO_TE_CTRL_CONNECTOR:
      {
        // The terminal connector control only has a get request with only the CUR attribute.
        audio_desc_channel_cluster_t ret;

        // Those are dummy values for now
        ret.bNrChannels = 1;
        ret.bmChannelConfig = (audio_channel_config_t) 0;
        ret.iChannelNames = 0;

        TU_LOG2("    Get terminal connector\r\n");

        return tud_audio_buffer_and_schedule_control_xfer(rhport, p_request, (void*) &ret, sizeof(ret));
      }
      break;

        // Unknown/Unsupported control selector
      default:
        TU_BREAKPOINT();
        return false;
    }
  }

  // Feature unit
  if (entityID == 2)
  {
    switch ( ctrlSel )
    {
      case AUDIO_FU_CTRL_MUTE:
        // Audio control mute cur parameter block consists of only one byte - we thus can send it right away
        // There does not exist a range parameter block for mute
        TU_LOG2("    Get Mute of channel: %u\r\n", channelNum);
        return tud_control_xfer(rhport, p_request, &mute[channelNum], 1);

      case AUDIO_FU_CTRL_VOLUME:
        switch ( p_request->bRequest )
        {
          case AUDIO_CS_REQ_CUR:
            TU_LOG2("    Get Volume of channel: %u\r\n", channelNum);
            return tud_control_xfer(rhport, p_request, &volume[channelNum], sizeof(volume[channelNum]));

          case AUDIO_CS_REQ_RANGE:
            TU_LOG2("    Get Volume range of channel: %u\r\n", channelNum);

            // Copy values - only for testing - better is version below
            audio_control_range_2_n_t(1)
            ret;

            ret.wNumSubRanges = 1;
            ret.subrange[0].bMin = -90;           // -90 dB
            ret.subrange[0].bMax = 90;      // +90 dB
            ret.subrange[0].bRes = 1;       // 1 dB steps

            return tud_audio_buffer_and_schedule_control_xfer(rhport, p_request, (void*) &ret, sizeof(ret));

            // Unknown/Unsupported control
          default:
            TU_BREAKPOINT();
            return false;
        }
      break;

        // Unknown/Unsupported control
      default:
        TU_BREAKPOINT();
        return false;
    }
  }

  // Clock Source unit
  if ( entityID == 4 )
  {
    switch ( ctrlSel )
    {
      case AUDIO_CS_CTRL_SAM_FREQ:
        // channelNum is always zero in this case
        switch ( p_request->bRequest )
        {
          case AUDIO_CS_REQ_CUR:
            TU_LOG2("    Get Sample Freq.\r\n");
            return tud_control_xfer(rhport, p_request, &sampFreq, sizeof(sampFreq));

          case AUDIO_CS_REQ_RANGE:
            TU_LOG2("    Get Sample Freq. range\r\n");
            return tud_control_xfer(rhport, p_request, &sampleFreqRng, sizeof(sampleFreqRng));

          // Unknown/Unsupported control
          default:
            TU_BREAKPOINT();
            return false;
        }
      break;

      case AUDIO_CS_CTRL_CLK_VALID:
        // Only cur attribute exists for this request
        TU_LOG2("    Get Sample Freq. valid\r\n");
        return tud_control_xfer(rhport, p_request, &clkValid, sizeof(clkValid));

      // Unknown/Unsupported control
      default:
        TU_BREAKPOINT();
        return false;
    }
  }

  TU_LOG2("  Unsupported entity: %d\r\n", entityID);
  return false;     // Yet not implemented
}

bool tud_audio_tx_done_pre_load_cb(uint8_t rhport, uint8_t itf, uint8_t ep_in, uint8_t cur_alt_setting)
{
  (void) rhport;
  (void) itf;
  (void) ep_in;
  (void) cur_alt_setting;

  for (uint8_t cnt=0; cnt < CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_N_TX_SUPP_SW_FIFO; cnt++)
  {
  //  tud_audio_write_support_ff(cnt, i2s_dummy_buffer[cnt], AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE/1000 * CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_N_BYTES_PER_SAMPLE_TX * CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_CHANNEL_PER_FIFO_TX);
  }

  return true;
}

bool tud_audio_tx_done_post_load_cb(uint8_t rhport, uint16_t n_bytes_copied, uint8_t itf, uint8_t ep_in, uint8_t cur_alt_setting)
{
  (void) rhport;
  (void) n_bytes_copied;
  (void) itf;
  (void) ep_in;
  (void) cur_alt_setting;

  uint16_t dataVal;

  // Generate dummy data
  // for (uint16_t cnt = 0; cnt < CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_N_TX_SUPP_SW_FIFO; cnt++)
  // {
  //   uint16_t * p_buff = i2s_dummy_buffer[cnt];              // 2 bytes per sample
  //   dataVal = 1;
  //   for (uint16_t cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE/1000; cnt2++)
  //   {
  //     for (uint8_t cnt3 = 0; cnt3 < CFG_TUD_AUDIO_FUNC_1_CHANNEL_PER_FIFO_TX; cnt3++)
  //     {
  //       *p_buff++ = dataVal;
  //     }
  //     dataVal++;
  //   }
  // }
  return true;
}

bool tud_audio_set_itf_close_EP_cb(uint8_t rhport, tusb_control_request_t const * p_request)
{
  (void) rhport;
  (void) p_request;

  return true;
}
```

Most of this code is copied from tinyusb examples, the goal is to setup USB microphone on RPI Pico that would stream live audio data towards the host.

Of course I also have some code that handles USB events in my main loop, not sure if I need to paste it as well since it's clear that some USB communication is taking place, allright.

The problem: seems that USB initialization fails on configuration stage. In dmesg I have:

```
[ 9304.017318] usb 1-12: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 9304.464998] usb 1-12: New USB device found, idVendor=fed0, idProduct=4010, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 9304.464999] usb 1-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 9304.465001] usb 1-12: Product: PicoMic
[ 9304.465001] usb 1-12: Manufacturer: PookyFan
[ 9304.465002] usb 1-12: SerialNumber: 42069
[ 9304.469981] usb 1-12: can't set config #1, error -32
```

I even tried debugging USB communication with Wireshark, though it didn't give me much information. It looks like it fails on SET CONFIGURATION Response:
[image: USB communication in Wireshark]

I don't know what is wrong with my code, although it's probably some stupid mistake that comes from lack of experience in using tinyusb library (and using low-level USB communication in general). All comments are more than welcome.

Comment: Since the error message is about a failed setup of the configuration, are you sure you can ignore `index` in `tud_descriptor_configuration_cb()`, for example?

Comment: I'm not sure of anything, but I think this particular part is working fine, as I see in debug data 500 mA and audio classes that I set in that descriptor I return through tud_descriptor_configuration_cb() - so I guess at least this part is okay.